# (2004 Lincoln Navigator) Trying to replace the key fob. Does the FCC ID have to match exactly for the new one to work?

Tags: key, fob, lincoln, navigator

The key fob I have right has the FCCID #CWTWB1U551

The third-party key fob I want to replace it with has the FCCID #CWTWB1U331

Will that key fob work with my vehicle?[image]

This is the key I want to buy: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07QBYQS7C/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_9-d2DbVVVXFRD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QBYQS7C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the one you provided will work. Keep in mind this is a 2 part key and remote still even tho its put in to one housing.

- The remote section you can program manually and that fcc id will work
  on the 04 Navigator.
- The transponder part (what starts the car) needs either 2 already programmed keys to program the new key manually (no tools needed) else you will need a proper scan tool/key programming tool to access the PATS system and program it.